# Laravel v5.2 moving middleware from web group to global?

Tags: laravel-5

I was logging request for my site, for guest users and authenticated users, but then i faced a problem that if a user is logged in and a 404 exception kick in then in that case i Auth::user() was null,

```
class LoggingMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }


    public function terminate($request, $response)
    {
        $info = [];
        //$info = get everything i need from request and response.
        $info['user_detail'] = Auth::user()->id;
        var_dump(Auth::user());
        dispatch(new LogRequests($info));
    }
}
```

what i did then moved the StartSession middle ware from web group to global middle ware group. Now it is working fine. Is there any issue that can arise by moving the middleware from web group to global?

Answer (score 0):

Global middleware is run every time an HTTP request is made to your application, so if the context of your `LoggingMiddleware` works with this in mind, then there should be no problem.

Comment: actually when the kernal starts handling the request it first run the global middleware then match the route from the requested route, if matched then run the other middleware groups, in case route is not matched it will not start session and we cannot get the user even from $request->user()

Comment: You're correct in your case, you won't be able to access the current user without moving it to the global group. What you've done should be fine. Edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: The code is still in testing phase, i just wanted to make sure if there is are any after affects of doing this.